# How can I explicitly typecast a pointer

Tags: c

I am trying to declare a variable pointer of data type int, to store the thread id
(i.e. myid) and then set that equal to explicit type cast to integer pointer of parameter vargp. But, when I try to output an ID number, I get an address as opposed to an actual value. The for loop is supposed to run for LOOP iterations. Here's what I have so far for the previous statement. `int *myid = (int *)vargp;` Here is the rest of the function.

```
void* threadFunction(void *vargp) {
  int LOOP = 0;
  unsigned long i = 0;
  int *myid = (int*) vargp;

  printf("\n-----------------------------\n");
  printf("\nThread %d has started\n", *myid);
  printf("\n-----------------------------\n");

  while (LOOP <= 5) {
    printf("\nThread ID %d is printing iteration %d", *myid, LOOP);
    LOOP++;
  }

  printf("\nThread %d has finished\n", *myid);
  return NULL;
}
```

I get `Thread ID -136702208 is printing iteration 0` as supposed to `Thread ID 1 is printing iteration 0` How can I fix this?

Here is the function that calls the threadfunction.

```
void multiThreads() {
  int SIZE = 5;
  int i = 0;
  int error;
  pthread_t tid[SIZE];

  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    error = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, threadFunction, (void*) &(tid[i]));
    if (error != 0) {
      printf("\nThread can't be created : [%s]", strerror(error));
    }

  } //end for

  while (i < SIZE) {
    pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you starting (i.e. calling) the thread?

Comment: I wrote a multithread function to call the threadFunction. Let me add it to the question

Comment: So you pass in `tid[i]` which is of type `pthread_t` and the man page says its content is "undefined" but calling code expects an `int *`.  Create an array or change tid to a struct of (pthread, int) of the ids, initialize in loop, and pass that in instead as arg.

Comment: Addresses are values too.

Comment: Perhaps initialize `pthread_t tid[SIZE] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50);` for more insight?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica wouldn't pthread_create overwrite those?

Comment: @AllanWind Yes, but if it did not, for _some reason_, output may be more illuminating.  We may have an issues that `int` and `pthread_t` differ in size.

Comment: @-chux-Reinstate initializing the array like that gives the error "error: variable-sized object may not be initialized"

Comment: @Y3LLZ True, `tid[]` is a VLA.  Could use `pthread_t tid[5] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50);` for debug or assigned the elements in a loop.

Comment: @chux I still get the weird numbers like before with ```tid[5]```

Comment: @Y3LLZ Rather than only say "weird numbers like before", it is often useful to say what those weird values were.

Comment: You have no idea what the value of a pthread_t is when you cast it to an int.

Comment: @AllanWind, detail, the casts are not applied to a `pthread_t` but to addresses like a `pthread_t *`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I am probably missing something so please spell it out.  op was passing in a `pthread_t *`, casting that to a `int *` and then deference it to get an int.  Btw, I was curious, so it looks like `nptl/bits/pthreadtypes.h` has private `typedef unsigned long int pthread_t`.

Comment: @AllanWind [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72007782/how-can-i-explicitly-typecast-a-pointer?noredirect=1#comment127237208_72007782) has "what the value of a pthread_t is when you cast it to an int.".  "it" seems to refer to "the value of a pthread_t".  But code does not cast a `pthread_t`.  Code casts a `pthread_t *` as in `(void*) &(tid[i])`.  This relates to OP's title question - yet the issue was not casting at all, but using a different object as your answer shows.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  You are trying to tell me that op confuses a pointer for it's value, right?  The cast `(void *)`doesn't do anything,  `tid[i]` is a `pthread_t`,  so `&tid[i]` is a `pthread_t *`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244205/discussion-between-chux-reinstate-monica-and-allan-wind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the content of a `pthread_t` is undefined, I changed `tid` to a `struct` that holds both the `pthread_t t` and the numeric `id` value you wanted.  Initialize the id and pass the address of `id` in as as arg.  Changed SIZE to size as uppercase is usually for values you define.  Using `main()` instead of `multiThreads()` to drive the unchanged `threadFunction()`:

```
int main() {
    int size = 5;
    struct {
        pthread_t t;
        int id;
    } threads[size];
    for(unsigned i=0; i < size; i++){
        threads[i].id = i + 1;
        int error = pthread_create(&threads[i].t, NULL, threadFunction, &threads[i].id);
        if(error) {
            printf("\nThread can't be created : [%s]", strerror(error));
        }
    }
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i].t, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here the snippet of the output:

```
                                                                                                                       
-----------------------------                                                                                          
                                                                                                                       
Thread 1 has started                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                       
-----------------------------                                                                                          
                                                           
Thread ID 1 is printing iteration 0                                                                                    
Thread ID 1 is printing iteration 1                       
Thread ID 1 is printing iteration 2                   
Thread ID 1 is printing iteration 3                        
Thread ID 1 is printing iteration 4                                                                                    
Thread ID 1 is printing iteration 5                 
Thread 1 has finished                                      
                                                                                                                       
-----------------------------                                                                                          
                                                           
Thread 5 has started                                       
                                                                                                                       
-----------------------------                                                                                          
                                                                                                                       
Thread ID 5 is printing iteration 0                       
Thread ID 5 is printing iteration 1                                                                                    
Thread ID 5 is printing iteration 2                                                                                    
Thread ID 5 is printing iteration 3                                                                                    
Thread ID 5 is printing iteration 4                 
Thread ID 5 is printing iteration 5                  
Thread 5 has finished                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                       
-----------------------------                         
                                                                                                                       
Thread 3 has started                                       
                                                           
-----------------------------             
                                                           
Thread 4 has started                                       
                                                           
-----------------------------                              
                                                           
Thread ID 4 is printing iteration 0
Thread ID 4 is printing iteration 1                                                                                    
Thread ID 4 is printing iteration 2                    
Thread ID 4 is printing iteration 3
```

Comment: Looks like a key difference between you and OP code is the use of a separate `ìnt` rather than a repeated use of the `pthread_t`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, because the content of pthread_t is undefined.  It could be addresses that he casts to ints.  If he wants the id to be 1, 2 ..., 5, then he has to use a separate variable with that value.